# How to set item in localSorage in realtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a child array nested into a data array,
onClick user inputs don't get saved in localStorage in realtime, but

For example
there are 4 Buttons with 4 different  user input
1,2,3,4
If the user clicks on 1, later click on 2 then the input of choice 1 gets into local storage, which means my function doesn't set it in real-time until the user clicks the next event or twice.

Related states

```
const deviceReport = localStorage.getItem('deviceReport') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('deviceReport')) : []  // this is in the parent component
const [data, setData] = useState(deviceReport) // this one placed in parent component and I'm passing in child component as parameter. 
const [childData, setChildData] = useState([]
```

) // That state is placed in the child component

childArrayHandler

```
const childArrayHandler = (sub, questionId) => {
    const hasId = childData.find(({ id }) => sub.id === id)
    // copy data to mutable object

    if (!hasId) {
      let newData = [...childData]
      newData = [...newData, { id: sub.id, sub_question: sub.sub_question, weightage: sub.weightage }]
      setChildData(newData)
    }
    //  find parent of the child
    const parent = data.find(({ parentId }) => questionId === parentId)
    // find index of parent
    const indexOfParent = data.indexOf(parent)
    // update data with child related to parent
    let newData = [...data]
    newData[indexOfParent].child = childData
    localStorage.setItem('deviceReport', JSON.stringify(newData)) // Here is a issue , 
    onDataChange(newData) // Updating the data in parent component state of data
  }
```

I want to update `deviceReport` which is in the `localStorage`, using the `childArrayHandler` function
This line

```
localStorage.setItem('deviceReport', JSON.stringify(newData))
```

Dosnt updated the storage in realtime and until user presses twice or click on another button in the option. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `localStorage.setItem` is synchronized; thus, it will update your state in real-time. However, it may not be correctly recalculated, for it is not a `state` in react.

To prevent this, you can use `useLocalStorageState` hook in `ahooks` instead of setting it manually:

https://ahooks.js.org/hooks/use-local-storage-state

---

If you want to manage the state in localstorage manually, you can do something like this:

```js
const [deviceReport, setDeviceReport] = useState([]);

// Try to retrieve from localstorage on init
useEffect(() => {
  try {
    let tmp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('deviceReport'))
    setDeviceReport(tmp);
  } catch {
  }
}, [])

// Set to localstorage when deviceReport change
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('deviceReport', JSON.stringify(deviceReport))
}, [deviceReport])
```

Comment: How can I fix the current function without using this ahook

Comment: Is the `childArrayHandler` in the parent component? or in the child component

Comment: It's in child component

Comment: I have it updated in the answer, the idea is, if you want to get the update, you need to use `state` instead of plain variable.

Comment: There might be some calculations issue while updating the childData , cz as u suggested there's still the same issue